# attemp to join incorrect SQL 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Want to join these 2 tables I have show the query I use on each individual and my attempt to join below. any help scripting would be much appreciated

```
SELECT [Date] = CONVERT(char(10), 
       CURRENT_TIMESTAMP -3, 103),
       Items = SUM(NumberOfItems), 
       'DUAL' as Sorter 
FROM  [DB2].[DB2].[dbo].[SortStatistics] 
WHERE RecordedPeriod  Between '06/23/17 01:00:00AM' and '06/23/17 23:59:00PM' 
AND   WorkstationID IN ('D11', 'D12', 'D13')

SELECT [Date] = CONVERT(char(10), 
       CURRENT_TIMESTAMP -3, 103), 
       Misfires = SUM(Resolved), 
       'DUAL' as Sorter
FROM  [DB1].[DB1].[dbo].[MisfireLog]
WHERE RecordedPeriod  Between '06/23/17 01:00:00AM' and '06/23/17 23:59:00PM' 
and   WorkstationID  IN ('D11', 'D12', 'D13')
```

Results are...

```
Date        Items   Sorter
23/06/2017  39983   DUAL


Date        Misfires    Sorter
23/06/2017  247         DUAL
```

Here is my attempt to join

```
SELECT [Date] = CONVERT(char(10), 
       CURRENT_TIMESTAMP -3, 103),Items = SUM(SortStatistics.NumberOfItems), 
       Misfires = SUM(MisfireLog.Resolved),
       'DUAL' as Sorter 
FROM [DB2].[DB2].[dbo].[SortStatistics] 
  LEFT JOIN [DB1].[DB1].[dbo].[MisfireLog]
    ON SortStatistics.RecordedPeriod = MisfireLog.RecordedPeriod
WHERE SortStatistics.RecordedPeriod  Between '06/23/17 01:00:00AM' and '06/23/17 23:59:00PM' 
AND   SortStatistics.WorkstationID IN ('D11', 'D12', 'D13') 
and   MisfireLog.WorkstationID IN ('D11', 'D12', 'D13')
```

Results from Join attempt shown like this, which is off some how

```
Date         Items  Misfires    Sorter
23/06/2017   691822 735         DUAL
```

Comment: do you want the output as 23/06/2017  39983   247   DUAL? then you need to do a cross join the tables after doing a `count` using `SELECT * FROM (query1)t1 CROSS JOIN (query2)t2;`

Comment: @ughai  do you mind by showing script, I have not worked with a cross join thus far, I appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you join the tables, on

```
SortStatistics.RecordedPeriod = MisfireLog.RecordedPeriod
```

The result will not contain the same no of records as the base table.

To get the result as

```
23/06/2017 39983 247 DUAL
```

you just need to concatenate the output of the 2 queries which you have. since its just a single row output for both, we can use `CROSS JOIN` like this

```
SELECT t1.[Date],t1.Items,t2.Misfires,t1.Sorter
FROM
(
SELECT [Date] = CONVERT(char(10), 
       CURRENT_TIMESTAMP -3, 103),
       Items = SUM(NumberOfItems), 
       'DUAL' as Sorter 
FROM  [DB2].[DB2].[dbo].[SortStatistics] 
WHERE RecordedPeriod  Between '06/23/17 01:00:00AM' and '06/23/17 23:59:00PM' 
AND   WorkstationID IN ('D11', 'D12', 'D13')
)t1
CROSS JOIN
(
SELECT [Date] = CONVERT(char(10), 
       CURRENT_TIMESTAMP -3, 103), 
       Misfires = SUM(Resolved), 
       'DUAL' as Sorter
FROM  [DB1].[DB1].[dbo].[MisfireLog]
WHERE RecordedPeriod  Between '06/23/17 01:00:00AM' and '06/23/17 23:59:00PM' 
and   WorkstationID  IN ('D11', 'D12', 'D13')
)t2;
```

Comment: perfect!!! Cheers @ughai.....what if I wanted to show....     `Percent = SUM(NumberOfItems) -  SUM(Resolved) / SUM(NumberOfItems)` Would I have to put on t1 and t2 query section?